# How to print "string" of first or last \label{string}, in running headers and margins, dictionary-like, with KOMA class?

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script, labels

I need to typeset a book where sections are identified by a string,  like "PLA 1", as dictated by the book's editor (the publisher calls these strings "cite-keys".)

Sometimes there are a few sections on a given book spread, which means a few cite-keys.

- These cite-keys need to be printed on the outer margin, on the same line as the section.
- Also, the first current cite-key of a left page must be printed in even-page running headers.
- The last current cite-key appearing on a right page must be in odd-page running headers.

How can one print those special strings in running headers and in margins?

I thought of using `\label{SCA 1}`, but then I realized `\labels` are actually counters.

I tried to use `\marks` (with the `emarks` package), but I can't figure it out.

Work-in-progress MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrpage2}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{\pagemark}
\ohead[\headmark]{\headmark}


\begin{document}
\section*{Section title}\label{PLA 1}
\lipsum[1]

Label string should be here \nameref{PLA 1}

\end{document}
```

I need to use Koma class. I saw somewhere people using `fancyhdr` or  `titlesec`, but Koma manual advice against either or them (for example, the `titlesec` package interferes with the option headings=optiontotoc).

I saw a few questions answered on http://tex.stackexchange.com, but none has enough pointers to get me started.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Your MWE doesn't really show a dictionary, it shows something you suppose is necessary for the solution, but probably it is not (see also [XY Problem](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2449)). Please make your code reflect what your true intention is. And btw, Section 10 of the `fancyhdr` manual describes a method that is not so much dependent on `fancyhdr` itself, you just ought to use the KOMA commands for modifying the headers instead of `\fancyhead`; this could make a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that particular `fancyhdr` section would possibly not disturb KOMA inner commands. The book is actually not a dictionary, perhaps more of a reference book. I will refine the MWE as soon as I can wrap my head around the `fancyhdr` example. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using the package `scrlayer-scrpage`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles

%%% alternatively:
%\usepackage[manualmark]{scrpage2}
%\clearscrheadfoot
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\chead{\pagemark}
\lehead*{\rightmark}\rohead*{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{}{}}

\newcommand\myaddsec[2]{%
  \needspace{3\baselineskip}%
  \addsec[#1]{#1\markboth{#2}{#2}\marginpar[\raggedright#2]{\raggedleft#2}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\myaddsec{Section title}{PLA1}
\lipsum[1]
\myaddsec{Section title}{PLA2}
\lipsum[1-3]
\myaddsec{Section title}{PLA3}
\lipsum[1]
\myaddsec{Section title}{PLA4}
\lipsum[1-5]
\myaddsec{Section title}{PLA5}
\lipsum[1]
\myaddsec{Section title}{PLA6}
\lipsum[1-2]

Label string should be here 

\end{document}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect. I was struggling with `fancyhdr`, as suggested by others, but they may not be aware that, if one uses many aspects of `koma` class, `fancyhdr` will interfere with it at some point. Your solution is simple and elegant. Very nice, thank you.